# div overlaps other on browser resize or resolution change

Tags: css, html

I have following html generated by my asp.net page. It looks good but when I change screen resolution of reduce browser size, image in logoplace div comes under/overlaps. It seems absolute positioning problem companyviewdiv

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="Mid_row">
                <div class="indent">                            
                    <div class="logoPlace">
                        <img width="200" height="172" border="0" src="images/aldagi.jpg">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="comapanyView">
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <h1>heading</h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    </div>      
</div>
```

and related css classes are:

```css
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 997px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    text-align: left;
}

#content {
    background: url(/images/bg.gif) top left repeat-x #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.Mid_row {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#content .indent {
    padding: 15px 0 0;
}

.logoPlace {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 15%;
}

.comapanyView {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the HTML that goes with that—preferably in a single template that we can copy and test. EDIT: O, I edited the post to make the HTML visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be fairly careful with absolute positioning, but it's not a real problem in this instance. The problem is being caused by the % width on the logo div, so I recommend you remove/rethink that:

```
.logoPlace {
    width: 15%; /*  REMOVE THIS */
}
```

EDIT: One option for making the text wrap around the logo might be to move the whole logo div into the DescribRow div, like so:

```
<div class="DescribRow">
    <div class="logoPlace">
    <img border="0" src="images/aldagi.jpg" width="200" height="172">
    </div>
```

The remove the old logoPlace styles and replace them with this:

```
.logoPlace {
    float: right;
    margin: -110px -20px 0 0;
}
```

The positioning might need some tweaking, but it might help.

Comment: OK, so what do you actually want there? Perhaps put the logoPlace CSS at the top so that we don't have to scroll miles to find it.

Comment: when i reduce browser size or resolution changes, image goes under the description which is on left side. I want to stay things on its place

Comment: I tried it but when I reduce browser window, image disappears

Comment: Could you update the fiddle (and perhaps strip out what's not necessary so we can focus on the relevant section)?